# JS rotating banners don't display in IE

Tags: javascript, rotation, ads

I currently have rotating banners in my site using JS. The banners appear in all browsers except for most versions of IE.

```
var banners = Array(); //The first element pushed in the array is at the index 0 

banners.push({link: '', target:'_blank', image: '', title: ''});

var rotate = function() {

//Find all images with class myImage
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImage');
var total  = images.length;

//Looping through all the elements found
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (banners.length == 0) {
          break;//No more banners can't display anymore
                }

    //Retrieve a random banner
     var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*banners.length));
    //Add the html to the element
    images[i].innerHTML = '<a href="'+banners[rnd].link+'" target="'+banners[rnd].target+'"><img src="'+banners[rnd].image+'" title="'+banners[rnd].title+'" /></a>'; //Added target blank and empty alt attribute
    banners.splice(rnd, 1);
}
}

    if (window.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
    window.addEventListener('load',rotate,false);
else if (window.attachEvent)  // IE DOM
     window.attachEvent("onload", rotate);
```

I then call in the banner using a simple div in my html.

```
< div class="myImage">< /div>
```

Any help would be hugely appriciated.

Thanks,
A

Comment: Please name at least one specific version of IE that does not work. Do you get any script errors?

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` was only added in IE9. To support IE8 you could use `querySelectorAll(".myImage")`, but for IE7 and below you will need to use something different, like a `name` attribute and `getElementsByName`.

That said, if there is only one such banner on the page, you can easily use `<div id="myImage">` and `getElementById` - this'll work even in ancient versions of IE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a promt reply. My page has several of these banners on it. Does that rule out the last option? Also, how does the name attribute work and would this method work for all versions? Thanks again

Comment: If your have more than one, then yes you should ignore my `getElementById` comment. The `name` attribute can be very vaguely thought of as "a `class` attribute for forms and JavaScript to hook into, as opposed to CSS"

Comment: ah, thanks, Ill give it a go. I have tried your querySelectorAll(".myImage") and it seems to work great. Hopefully most users will have at least IE8! Thanks a lot! A

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in most versions of IE.

I notice that you're also using other IE-specific code for your event listeners.

This kind of thing is exactly the reason why libraries like jQuery have been written. All the functionality you need is available in jQuery, and is completely cross-browser compatible. I don't know if you're using it already, but I would strongly recommend it as the solution to your problem here; it will make your code a lot neater.

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var banners = Array(); //The first element pushed in the array is at the index 0 
    banners.push({link: '', target:'_blank', image: '', title: ''});

    //Find all images with class myImage
    $('.myImage').each(function() {
        //Looping through all the elements found
        if (banners.length == 0) {
              return; //No more banners can't display anymore
        }

        //Retrieve a random banner
        var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*banners.length));
        //Add the html to the element
        $(this).html('<a href="'+banners[rnd].link+'" target="'+banners[rnd].target+'"><img src="'+banners[rnd].image+'" title="'+banners[rnd].title+'" /></a>'); //Added target blank and empty alt attribute
        banners.splice(rnd, 1);
    }
});
```

Much shorter than your code, and easier to read too. It could be made even shorter and more efficient, but all I had time for now was to modify your existing code to jQuery style. I hope it demonstrates my point anyway.